Tensorflow fit() function: steps_per_epoch = 1 causes oscillations in loss
I have a simple convolutional neural network that takes an input of size (5,5,3). The code of the training is added below. As you can see input is generated randomly and, only a single entry is used to train the model.
tf.random.set_seed(1)
X_train = tf.random.uniform((1,5,5,3), seed = 1)
y_train = np.array([[0, .5, 0., 0., 0., .0 , 0 , 0, 0, 0 ]])

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 6, kernel_size=5, strides = 1, activation= "relu", input_shape = (5,5,3)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 40
history = model.fit(
        X_train,
        y_train,
        epochs = epochs,
        batch_size = 1,
        steps_per_epoch = 1,
        verbose = 0,
)
plt.plot(history.history["loss"])

The training is done for 40 epochs and it obvious that steps_per_epoch is equal to 1. However, assigning 1 to steps_per_epoch makes the training process act strange. Doing this causes the loss to drop to 0 instantly, and then rise back up. The image is stated below:
Image: Loss when steps_per_epoch = 1
On the other hand, not passing steps_per_epoch to the fit function, or passing 0 or numbers greater than 1, solves the problem, and we see a normal behavior from the learning process.
Image: Loss when we don't pass steps_per_epoch to fit function
Where does this problem come from? Can any one shed some light on this matter? Shouldn't steps_per_epoch be equal to one when we have a single training data and batch_size is 1
P.s. I'm using Tensorflow 2.17.0
P.s. I tried changing learning rate, It didn't solve the problem. A picture of the loss in the training process when LR is decreased to 0.0001 is depicted below:
Image: lr = 0.0001
To solve this problem, I did a lot of trials and errors and realized that this is caused by steps_per_epoch being equal to 1.
